# What is the function that will provide you the lower and upper bounds of correlation coefficient separately?

Tags: r, correlation

```
m=c(1,2,5,4,6,8)
h=c(1,2,9,8,7,3)
cor(m,h)
#[1] 0.4093729
```

If you estimate the correlation coefficient (R), then you can also estimate a `95%` confidence interval for  correlation coefficient (R), resulting in, for example something like

```
 R = 0.40  [0.33 0.56]
```

where the "best" estimate for R is `0.40` and there's a `95%` chance that the true R is between `0.3` and `0.56`.  (Note that these numbers are completely made up.)

I am looking for a function, which will provide  the lower and upper bounds of R separately .
To have something like:

```
 R = 0.40
upper  [0.33]
 lower [0.56]
```

something simiilar to this in `MATLAB`:

```
         [R,P,RLO,RUP]=corrcoef(...) also returns matrices RLO and RUP, of the same size as R,            
         containing lower and upper bounds for a 95% confidence interval for each coefficient.
```

Comment: The confidence interval tells you already the lower and upper bounds

Comment: The chance that the true R is between 0.3 and 0.56 is not necessarily, or even likely 95%.  The "95%" in the CI description is about the procedure for creating it and tells you that the procedure would capture the true value 95% of the time.  That's actually quite different from what you said (http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26450/601).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the "see also" section of `cor`'s help page, it says

> cor.test for confidence intervals (and tests)

```
> cor.test(m, h)

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  m and h
t = 0.8974, df = 4, p-value = 0.4202
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.6022868  0.9164582
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.4093729
```

Or to get at the interval more directly:

```
> x = cor.test(m, h)
> x$conf.int
[1] -0.6022868  0.9164582
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get only the upper bound?

Comment: is there a way to provide the lower and upper bounds of R separately? `example`> x$conf.int(upper)` `or` `> x$conf.int(lower)`

Comment: @sacvf: The `$conf.int` part is just a vector with the two values in it, so you can do `x$conf.int[1]` for the lower bound and `x$conf.int[2]` for the upper, same as any other vector.