# R extract or split an interval into vectors

Tags: r, split, intervals

What is this operation called and how do I achieve this? (I can't find an example.)

Given

```
temp1
               Var1 Freq
1          (0,0.78]    0
2       (0.78,0.99]    0
3       (0.99,1.07]    0
4      (1.07,1.201]    1
5     (1.201,1.211]    0
6      (1.211,1.77]    2
```

How do I split the intervals in `Var1` into two vectors for `start` and `end`?

Like this

```
df2
  start   end Freq
1 0.000 0.780    0
2 0.780 0.990    0
3 0.990 1.070    0
4 1.070 1.201    1
5 1.201 1.211    0
6 1.211 1.770    2
```

Comment: I think you can easily adapt the examples from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32087497/split-one-column-into-two-columns-and-retaining-the-seperator

Comment: does this also help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808560/what-is-the-function-that-will-provide-you-the-lower-and-upper-bounds-of-correla

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't need to have that format to fix in the first place.
E.g.:

```
x <- 1:10
brks <- c(0,5,10)
data.frame(table(cut(x,brks)))

#    Var1 Freq
#1  (0,5]    5
#2 (5,10]    5

data.frame(start=head(brks,-1), end=tail(brks,-1), Freq=tabulate(cut(x,brks)))

#  start end Freq
#1     0   5    5
#2     5  10    5
```

Comment: Good call on the XY problem :-)